# Делаю поиск по Listview, выводит ошибку

Tags: android, java

Делаю поиск по `Listview`:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
```

выводит ошибку:

> The method filter(String) is undefined for the type
>   ParseQueryAdapter

```
public class SearchUsers extends Activity {

    EditText editText;
    ListView listView;
    Button button;
    ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser> parseAdapter;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_users);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseUser> factory2 = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public ParseQuery<ParseUser> create() {
                ParseQuery<ParseUser> user = ParseUser.getQuery();

                return user;
            }
        };

        // Set up the query adapter
        parseAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser>(this, factory2) {
            @Override
            public View getItemView(ParseUser user, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (view == null) {
                    view = View.inflate(getContext(),
                            R.layout.anywall_post_item2, null);
                }
                super.getItemView(user, view, parent);
                TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contentView2);
                name.setText(user.getString("username"));
                users = user.getString("username");


                return view;

            }
        };


        listView.setAdapter(parseAdapter);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) { // Когда, юзер изменяет текст он работает


                    String text = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                parseAdapter.**filter**(text);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для использования фильтра, адаптер должен реализовать интерфейс `Filterable`.